# onclick with same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, toggle

I have Div1 and Div2 inside this divs i have multiple inputs.
The goal is when i click on div 1 btn edit it shows the inputs inside div 1 and the same to div2

My html

My 1º Div

```
   <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 xxx">
       <div class="row form-group ">
           <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6"><h6 >xxx Nº 1</h6></div> 
                 <div id="edit" class="btn btn-sm"> Edit </div> 
            </div>
            <div class="form-group  edit_xxx" id="edit_xxx">
                <div class="row form-group" >
                        <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 row">
                            <div id="minus" class="btn btn-sm-click btn-info fa fa-minus pull-left"></div>

                                <input id="xxx" name="xxx" class="form-control click select-form" disabled type="text" value="{{ $i }}" >

                            <div id="plus" class="btn btn-sm-click btn-info fa fa-plus pull-right"></div>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                     </div>
                        </div>
```

My 2º div

```
                        <div class="row form-group " >
                              <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6"><h6 >xxx Nº 2</h6></div> 
                            <div id="edit" class="btn btn-sm"> Edit </div> 
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group  edit_xxx" id="edit_xxx">

                    <div class="row form-group" >

                        <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 row">
                            <div id="minus" class="btn btn-sm-click btn-info fa fa-minus pull-left"></div>

                                <input id="xxx" name="xxx" class="form-control click select-form" disabled type="text" value="{{ $i }}" >

                            <div id="plus" class="btn btn-sm-click btn-info fa fa-plus pull-right"></div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                       </div>
                        </div>
```

My jquery code:

```
    $("body").on("click", ".xxx",function(){ 
      $(this).parent().find(".edit_xxx").toggle();
   });
```

The final goal is when click inside .xxx it opens the input id click again closes the input from DIV1 the same if click on div2

Thanks for the help, i realy suck with jquery.

Answer (score 0):

The answer!

```
$("body").on("click", "#edit",function(){
          $(this).parents(".xxx").children("#edit_xxx").toggle();
  });
```